# paint drywall -- corners first?

Tags: drywall, painting, repainting

I watched a few videos on `rolling` a drywall, and I still don't quite understand one thing -- is it important to paint all the corners, and then only paint the remaining space. In my opinion, this way I'd get gradient colors and the corners would look different from the rest of the wall.

Does it matter, if I paint a very first coat, or re-paint with new color?

Is it just a matter of habit/taste?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters because a brush transfers more paint than a roller and leaves marks in the finish. By cutting in the edges first and following with the roller you spread the brushed on paint further leveling the finish while removing brush marks. In other words the rolled finish, which is what you want, goes as close to the corner as you can get without bumping. (about 1/4" away) If you roll first the corners would have a brushed finish the width of the brush, which is much wider.

The same argument applies, and is more obvious, in cases like textured finish. You want the final finish technique applied last, for maximum coverage.

Comment: +1 - Also, if you feather out your strokes and practice proper "loading" of the brush, none should be obviously visible through the roller coat. I will "cut-in" a whole room, with sometimes two coats, prior to rolling. People don't walk into a room and stare at the paint, it's what catches their eye from a glance, that earns their criticism. I voted yours up, because it was the most logical of the three - but it can still be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to "cut in" or paint the corners and close to the trim by brush then roll the rest making sure to overlap the hand painted area. I think this is to keep from having the roller hitting the wall at the corner or getting paint on the trim. I do 1 section at a time so there is no real difference in the color, I never questioned why we did it this way but when trying different ways later found the roller hitting the wall and figured this was the reason I was taught to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't paint "all" the corners, because most will dry before you get to them. Paint the corners first, as you go along, to maintain a wet edge. Also, when painting corners, feather the edge so you don't get a bump under the rolled paint.

Comment: thanks for comment. What means "feather the edges"?

Comment: As you paint the corners and edges, let the paint get thinner where the roller will go. That way you don't see a bump underneath when you do the main rolling. In the same way a feather gets thinner and flatter toward the edges.